# Comparison of dataAdapter .Fill and .Update

Tags: c#, database, dataadapter

I've been reading through the MSDN resources and several forums and still don't understand what's the difference between those two `dataAdapter.Fill()` and `dataAdapter.Update()`, I tried to use both of them to update the database from my program and it works, but when I try to remove the `update()` function, it is still working perfectly, therefore I think of it as useless.

Can anyone please clarify this?

Edit:
this is my code to delete:

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\inventorySystem\\branches\\Database\\inventorySystemDatabase.accdb";
string query = "DELETE FROM Product WHERE product_id=" + productDataGridView[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);
OleDbCommandBuilder deleteBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
DataTable deleteTable = new DataTable();
dAdapter.Update(deleteTable);
```

-- I have to make an extra select command to update the datagridview --

Comment: Can you please share your codes?

Comment: @AndrewTaswin - added a sample code, check the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working sample

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection con =
            new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"C:\\test.mdb\";");

        private OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
        DataTable table = new DataTable("person"); 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            ;
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select ID, p_name, p_age from person", con);
            adapter.Fill(table);
            OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
            adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
            adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow[] row = table.Select("p_age = 10");
            if (row.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
                {
                    row[i].Delete();
                }
            }
            adapter.Update(table);
        }

    }
}
```

In simple words.

[DataAdapter.Fill()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t.aspx) is used to load data from database

Example : Showing Data From database to gridview

```
using (DataTable table = new DataTable()) {

    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select name,age from person", conObject)) {

        adapter.Fill(table);
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource { DataSource = table };
        dgReader.DataSource = bs;    
    }

}
```

and once the edits are done, the [DataAdapter.Update()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx) commits all the changed data information to the database using the underlying connection.

**[DataAdapter.Fill()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t.aspx)**

> The Fill method retrieves rows from the data source using the SELECT
>   statement specified by an associated SelectCommand property. The
>   connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be valid,
>   but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed before
>   Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If the
>   connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open.
>
> The Fill operation then adds the rows to destination DataTable objects
>   in the DataSet, creating the DataTable objects if they do not already
>   exist. When creating DataTable objects, the Fill operation normally
>   creates only column name metadata. However, if the MissingSchemaAction
>   property is set to AddWithKey, appropriate primary keys and
>   constraints are also created.

**[DataAdapter.Update()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx)**

> The update is performed on a by-row basis. For every inserted,
>   modified, and deleted row, the Update method determines the type of
>   change that has been performed on it (Insert, Update or Delete).
>   Depending on the type of change, the Insert, Update, or Delete command
>   template executes to propagate the modified row to the data source.
>   When an application calls the Update method, the DataAdapter examines
>   the RowState property, and executes the required INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statements iteratively for each row, based on the order of the
>   indexes configured in the DataSet. For example, Update might execute a
>   DELETE statement, followed by an INSERT statement, and then another
>   DELETE statement, due to the ordering of the rows in the DataTable.
>
> It should be noted that these statements are not performed as a batch
>   process; each row is updated individually. An application can call the
>   GetChanges method in situations where you must control the sequence of
>   statement types (for example, INSERT before UPDATE). For more
>   information, see Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters (ADO.NET).

Comment: if I use my code for deleting, it is not updated using dataAdapter.update() and I have to recall the select command to review the database. Is that a right way to do it?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! So if you dont mind, I will reexplain my understanding. So if I send my delete query to the database, it will remodify the database directly so I dont have to update it, but if I change the datatable in the program, I have to update the database after changing its value, am I right?

Comment: it will modify the Database directly, but since u have already loaded rows in DataTable, items wont be deleted from DataTable but directly from Database, hence adapter as assigned update, delete & insert command via property. so whenever the update command is called all of them are called

Comment: from MSDN : Update(DataTable) -> Calls the respective INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements for each inserted, updated, or deleted row in the specified DataTable.

Comment: one bug fixed in my code i have changed a line under btnDelete_Click from table.Rows.Remove(row[i]); to row[i].Delete();

Comment: adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
what is this 3 used for?

Comment: instead to creating command manually(which can be painful at a time), OleDbCommandBuilder is used : The OleDbDataAdapter does not automatically generate the SQL statements required to reconcile changes made to a DataSet/DataTable with the associated data source. However, you can create an OleDbCommandBuilder object to automatically generate SQL statements for single-table updates if you set the SelectCommand property of the OleDbDataAdapter. Then, any additional SQL statements that you do not set are generated by the OleDbCommandBuilder.

Comment: adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
i got an exception here - Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.

Answer (score 4):

For short the definition.

`DataAdapter.Fill()` stands for *SELECT* query statement to database from the Server.

```
// 1
// Open connection
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(
        Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnectionString))
{
   c.Open();
   // 2
   // Create new DataAdapter
   using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EmployeeIDs", c))
     {
      // 3
      // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
         DataTable t = new DataTable();
         a.Fill(t);

         // 4
         // Render data onto the screen
         // dataGridView1.DataSource = t; // <-- From your designer
    }
  }
```

`DataAdapter.Update()` stands for *Update*, *Insert* and *Delete* query statement to database from the Server.

```
public DataSet CreateCmdsAndUpdate(DataSet myDataSet,string myConnection,string mySelectQuery,string myTableName) 
{
    OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(myConnection);
    OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConn);
    OleDbCommandBuilder custCB = new OleDbCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);

    myConn.Open();

    DataSet custDS = new DataSet();
    myDataAdapter.Fill(custDS);

    //code to modify data in dataset here

    //Without the OleDbCommandBuilder this line would fail
    myDataAdapter.Update(custDS);

    myConn.Close();

    return custDS;
 }
```

Reference:
[C# SqlDataAdapter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter)
[DataAdapter.Update Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: so basically I still have to use .fill() while deleting?

Comment: no. just use delete. my answer is just an example, obviously we should use the `Fill` before we can `Update`.